# EEA Resident Card

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, resident-permit, eu-spouses, residence-cards

My husband a non Eea national  will be coming to the UK soon as he was recently granted his EEA FP 
how long should a non- Eea national who is on an EEA Family Permit wait before applying for a resident card and also how long does it take to get it. And should we books tickets for a full 6 months or is it ok if we just book or a few months then change ticket.

Comment: Note that any answer to this question may change dramatically over the coming years, should the UK vote to leave the European Union, depending on whether or not it will subsequently join the EEA.

Comment: You can do whatever you want with tickets.  You can arrive with a 1-way ticket or you can come with a round trip ticket that takes you back the next day.  They can't take into account your travel plan, nor your means, because you are traveling under the freedom of movement directive.